# jQuery Change click behavior in Edit Mode

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I have a simple media gallery with images that click through to other pages. I also have an "Edit" mode that allows the user to change the media gallery name, description and delete photos etc. While in "Edit" mode, I'd like to disable the default click action on the photos, and make it so that you can "select" multiple images when clicking on them. Then, buy clicking "Cancel"  or "OK", the regular default image click HREFs are restored. I have the following code that kind of works in parts, but I am getting strange behavior. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here or a better way to achieve this?

```
$(".editAlbumButton").click(function() {
    $("#editTools").show();
    $(".mediaClick").preventDefault();
    $(".mediaClick").toggle(function() {
        $(this).addClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
    });
}); 

$(".cancelButton").click(function() {
    $(".mediaClick").removeClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
    $("#editTools").hide();
    $(".mediaClick"). ??? (); // I don't know how to "Restore" default click action here ?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you use a flag for example editable.

```
var editable=false;
$(".editAlbumButton").click(function() {
    $("#editTools").show();
    editable=true;
    $(".mediaClick").toggle(function() {
        $(this).addClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
    });
});
$(".cancelButton").click(function() {
    $(".mediaClick").removeClass('mediaSelectHighlight');
    $("#editTools").hide();
    editable=false;
});
$(".mediaClick").click(function() {
    if(editable){
        $(this).preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andres - that worked. I was wondering if you could tell me. Ultimately I want to disable .mediaClick default and then use ".toggle()" to toggle a class on .mediaClick. Is there a way to use toggle if editable = true?

Comment: well if you want to toogle, if is or not editable before the if(editable) you can make any code you want and always is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)ing and [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)ing the events, depending on which mode is active.

```
$(".editAlbumButton").click(function() {
    $(".mediaclick").unbind("click", /*hanlder*/);
}
...
$(".cancelButton").click(function() {
   $(".mediaclick").bind("click", /*handler*/);
}
```